# Best way to iterate through a for loop, and then iterate through it again backwards?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, iterator

I found that when writing animations I sometimes run into having to go through a for loop once, then iterate the value down afterwards. This was generally used for jump animations, or disappear then appear again animations.

Here's an example of what I had done -

```
// Make the sprite slowly disappear
for (int i = 256; i > 0; --i)
{
    sprite.opacity(i);
    draw();
}

// Make the sprite slowly appear again
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    sprite.opacity(i);
    draw();
}
```

Every time I did this I had a deep feeling that it was too much. What would be a nicer way of going about this? I'm not entirely sure what would be best practice. I imagine I could use `reverse_iterator`, but I'm also not sure how I would implement it.

Comment: You're spot on that it is "too much": this was a common problem with C++. In C++11, some of your loops can be written as a rang-based for loop, else you're pretty much SOL.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approche

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicating code, maybe a lambda is a good idea

Comment: The range of values used for `i` in the first loop is wrong. You want to use `for ( int i = 255; i >= 0; i-- )`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the use of `<cmath>` abs() function:

```
for( int i = -255; i <= 255; i++)
    use( abs( i ) );
```

Comment: +1 better than i wrote. i wonder how it's possible to introduce such complexity as a subtraction to implement a trapezoid function, as i did, and @varaquilex apparently also did. hm.

Comment: How's the cost of this compared to two loops without `abs` ?

Comment: Having one copy of a code instead of two to handle, expand and correct – priceless!  :)

Comment: This is clever CiaPan, I like this a lot! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the absolute value function `abs()` defined in `<cmath>`. It will halve the code written in your case.

```
for(int i=0; i<512; ++i)
{
    sprite.opacity( abs(256-i) );
    draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a great way to iterate through a loop both forward and "in reverse" - one commonly used by C++ programmers.

For your sprite, it appears that the 256 range (you might consider setting a `const int RGB_RANGE` equal to 256 - or a more appropriate identifier) is all that is needed; however, were the size of your object dynamic, you could also consider using the `.size()` function (something like an `ArrayList` or a `vector` - here is where something like an iterator would be useful):

```
for (i = 9; i < RGB_RANGE; i++)
{
    // CODE
}
```

The above code being an example of the first `const` suggestion. Remember, simple code is never a bad thing - it means you are doing something right.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the situation you are describing, you have to iterate through the sprites to set the opacity of each sprite.  Whether you use a for loop, or a reverse_iterator, the time spent is going to be the same.  Any implementation of the reverse_iterator will still have to iterate through each sprite.  There might be ways to make it easier to read, but in the end the algorithm will come down to the same.  For example, you could take advantage of the stack and call the sprites recursively to increase the opacity and then decrease on the way back out; however, I see no gain in doing so the algorithm time would still end up being the same.

In some cases, you just need to bite the bullet and spend the time doing things in a way that may seem like (or even be) brute force.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `abs`, I'd go with something like :

```
template<typename Func>
void animate (size_t step_count, Func && f)
{
    size_t step;

    for (step = step_count ; step > 0 ; --step)
        f(step - 1);

    for (step = 1 ; step < step_count ; ++step)
        f(step);
}
```

Use case :

```
animate(256, [](size_t step)
{
    sprite.opacity(step);
    draw();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to just iterate a range up and down again, you can go the very crazy route and just define a "container" (or range, in boost lingo) that provides iterators (well, technically they are more almost-iterators) which allow you to express exactly what you intend to do:

```
for(auto i : down_and_up(3)) ::std::cout << i << "\n";
```

For example should print

```
3
2
1
0
1
2
```

Sadly, there is not much support in the standard library for types like this, although boost provides [`boost::iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html), [`boost::counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html),  and [`boost::join`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html) that, in concert with [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator), can provide `down_and_up`. Writing one yourself if fairly simple (although verbose), as long as you do not completely abuse it:

```
struct down_and_up
{
    size_t from;
    down_and_up(size_t const from) : from(from) { }
    struct iterator : public ::std::iterator<::std::forward_iterator_tag, size_t> {
        size_t cur;
        bool down;

        iterator(size_t cur, bool down) : cur(cur), down(down) { }

        size_t operator*() const { return cur; }
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            if(down)
            {
                --cur;
                if(0 == cur) down = false;
            }
            else ++cur;
            return *this;
        }
        friend bool operator==(iterator const& lhs, iterator const& rhs) { return lhs.down == rhs.down && lhs.cur == rhs.cur; }
        friend bool operator!=(iterator const& lhs, iterator const& rhs) { return lhs.down != rhs.down || lhs.cur != rhs.cur; }
    };


    iterator begin() const { return iterator{ from, true }; }
    iterator end() const { return iterator{ from, false }; }
};
```

Note: If you wish, you can easily extend it with more container capabilities, like a `value_type` member typedef, but this definition is enough for the above example.

P.S.: The boost way, for your entertainment:

```
boost::iterator_range<boost::counting_iterator<size_t>> up(boost::counting_iterator<size_t>(0), boost::counting_iterator<size_t>(3));
boost::iterator_range<std::reverse_iterator<boost::counting_iterator<size_t>>> down(
    std::reverse_iterator<boost::counting_iterator<size_t>>(boost::counting_iterator<size_t>(4)),
    std::reverse_iterator<boost::counting_iterator<size_t>>(boost::counting_iterator<size_t>(1)));

for(auto i : boost::join(down, up)) ::std::cout << i << "\n";
```